# Generic function template deduction over existing function overloads

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm writing an extensible library where it has become convenient to overload STL's `to_string()` for custom types. For that I've designed a generic overload template that throws an exception if not specialized:

```
namespace std {
// ...
template < typename T >
inline std::string to_string(const T& in, const std::string& separator = ",") {
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid call to " + std::string(__func__) + "(): missing template specialization for type " + typeid(T).name());
}

}  // namespace std
```

This is useful mainly because the description will provide a clear explanation on the issue and how to solve it, and avoids having to use polymorphism to implement derived implementations (the function is only marginally/optionally required for certain applications such as serialization, I/O, etc.).

However, the issue with this approach is that the overload template will be deduced even with types where `<string>` already provides an overload for.

My question is *if is there a way to force the non-template overload to be used only when there is no non-template definition available*?

Comment: Orthogonal, but use `static_assert()`, not `throw` in this case and don't specialize `std`, that's the source of many issues.

Comment: To answer the question - add some more argument(s) with default value(s)

Comment: If this is made to work, the error will occur at runtime, a runtime exception. Simply by ... not doing any of this the error will now be reported at compile time, and not runtime. Which is a much better place to be in.

Comment: The point of specializing `std` was so that other code could use it interchangeably for both basic types where `std::to_string` is defined, as well as user-defined custom classes. Renaming the function would force me to wrap around `std::to_string` for those basic types such as `float`, `double`, etc - which I guess is a valid solution.

Comment: @joaocandre Basically extending `std` is UB with a few exceptions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: Also, there's a workaround: `namespace joaotl { using namespace std; /* your codes */ }`. Then you can write `joaotl` instead of `std` for `to_string` and it'll deduce either the standard or yours, yet you don't need to extend `std`. You still need the 'add a parameter' trick, however.

Comment: *"if is there a way to force the non-template overload to be used only when there is no non-template definition available"* With overload resolution, there is already a tie-breaker between non-template versus template (in favor in non-template).

Comment: @joaocandre What's the purpose of getting a runtime exception instead of a compilation error?

Comment: @TedLyngmo In truth I initially tried to use `static_assert`, but I was having trouble with the proper syntax - it either never compiled or compiled when it should, so I went to the very next thing. Though I'd say it's simpler to provide type information during runtime trough `<typeinfo>` - doing similar at compile time seemed quite convoluted,

Comment: @joaocandre Something that will _always_ fail in runtime should be caught at compiletime if possible. It's not particularly convoluted as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you do not generate a runtime exception for something that should be a compilation failure.

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace extra {
template <class T>
inline std::string to_string(const T& in) {
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "T needs extra::to_string overload");
    return std::to_string(in); 
}
}  // namespace extra
```

... and then you don't need to check if it's an arithmetic type at the call site:

```cpp
template <class T>
void func(const T& arg) {
    std::cout << extra::to_string(arg);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cGvvccG98)

Comment: I hate to "well actually" an otherwise solid answer, but... `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, T>, ...)` is IFNDR. One cannot specialize `is_same` or `is_same_v`, so that is always false, and implementations may reject the code. It relies on the compiler not being too smart. (See https://wg21.link/p2593 and p1830 and p1936.) But you can always rewrite it to be valid, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/rP1nf9xah Anyways, I love C++... :)

Comment: Thanks @JeffGarrett - that would be cleaner even if my original would have been ok. I need to read up on the paragraphs you shared. They _do_ list `static_assert(always_false<T>::value);` as a valid workaround which is pretty close to my `!is_same<T,T>`. Need to understand the difference.

Comment: *Amusingly*, the difference is that `always_false<T>::value` may be true. The language in the standard in [temp.res.general](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6.1) which makes this IFNDR is "no valid specialization can be generated". I think of it as ensuring whatever "grammatically correct" code you may write in a template, it has to "make sense". Uninstantiated templates have to be represented internally by the compiler and this limits the scope of what they must represent. I'm not sure if that's the motivation, but it's how I think of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no carve-out for static_assert failures. That carve-out is what p2593 proposes. It follows that you can't simply `static_assert(false)`. `std::is_same` has its behavior dictated by the standard (so `std::is_same<T, T>::value` will be true) and it is forbidden to specialize it (so we *know* in all specializations it will always be true for all types). But with `always_false`, there is no rule forbidding specializing it, so it can be specialized at a type `T`, such that `always_false<T>::value` is true. Therefore, we can construct a valid specialization.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Nasty :-) I thought I might get away with creating a type trait that did `std::is_same<T, class_private_class>` internally, but ... seems like that's not possible then. Anyway, thanks for checking up on this - and the answer became cleaner without that uglyness I had at first  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up declaring `to_string` on a different namespace, and made use of type traits to delegate basic types towards STL's `std::to_string`:

```
namespace extra {

template < typename T >
struct invalid : std::false_type { /* ... */ };

template < typename T >
inline std::string to_string(const T& in) {
    // static_assert(invalid< iT >::value, "Invalid call to extra::to_string(): missing template specialization for required type!");   // never compiles
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid call to extra::_to_string(): missing template specialization for required types[" + std::string(typeid(T).name()) + "]!");
}

}  // namespace extra


template < typename T >
void func(const T& arg) {
    // ...
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic< T >()) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(arg);
    } else {
        std::cout << extra::to_string(arg);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Although I am still trying to figure out how to proper write the static assertion in order to generate the error during compilation, at this stage this behaves how I needed it to.